# Updating OpenSSL for Apache 1.3.41

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, openssl

I need to upgrade a Mac OS X Server (10.4.11) box's openssl to 0.9.8o and was wondering about the process. Will I need to rebuild Apache with the new version of OpenSSL or will I be able to just update OpenSSL and be done with it? If I do need to rebuild, what's the best method in OS X Server and keep all my current configurations?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Apache 1.3.x is out of date. You should upgrade to Apache 2.2. I don't think you'll find an easy way to upgrade OpenSSL with an out of date software.